# using Stash to output a language variable with Transcribe

Tags: stash, variable, transcribe

In my article template I'm doing this:

```
{exp:stash:set name="article_lang" parse_vars="yes" parse_depth="2" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
    {exp:switchee variable="{transcribe:language_abbreviation}" parse="inward"}
       {case value="en"}/{/case}
       {case default="Yes"}/{transcribe:language_abbreviation}/{/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Because the previous developer didn't set up Transcribe properly

Then in my template layout I'm doing

```
<div class="article__meta">
    <span class="article__category">{exp:stash:get_list name='article_category'}<a href="{exp:stash:get name='article_lang'}{cat_url}">{cat_name}{/exp:stash:get_list}</a></span>
    / <span class="article__author">{exp:stash:get_list name="authors" backspace="7"}<a href="{exp:stash:get name='article_lang'}{author_url}">{author_name}</a> &amp; {/exp:stash:get_list}</span>
  </div>
```

Now this works great for the Spanish and French articles, but for some reason, when we're on English, the `{exp:stash:get name='article_lang'}` variable is spitting out a date.

If I call that variable outside of the get_list, it returns the variable I'd expect.

Any ideas?